# I'm trying to make a calculator using octave menu function, but there is parse error at the code, but idk how to locate or identified it

Tags: matlab, user-interface, octave, calculator, parse-error

```
 OCH

error: parse error near line 156 of file C:\Users\exonc\OCH.m

  syntax error
```

the octave keep reporting like that

below is my script

```
    total=0
choice=menu(' Welcome to Group 8 Open Channel Hydraulic Calculator click continue to start',' continue');
a=menu(' Please choose unit system', 'SI Units','U.S. Customary Units');
if a==1
  choice= menu ('Please choose shape of the channel', 'Rectangle', 'Triangle','Trapezoid');
  if (choice==1)
    prompt= {'channel top width,b (meter)',' Channel depth,y(meter)','Channel height,h(meter)','Channel length,L(meter)', 'Mannings coefficient,n'};
    dlg_title='Please insert channel dimension'
    num_lines=1;
    answer= inputdlg(prompt, dlg_title,num_lines);
     top_width=str2double(answer{1});
    channel_depth= str2double(answer{2});
    channel_height=str2double(answer{3});
    channel_length=str2double(answer{4});
    n=str2double(answer{5});
    Area= top_width*channel_depth;
    Wetted_Perimeter= top_width+2*channel_depth;
    Hydraulic_Radius= Area/Wetted_Perimeter;
    K=1.00;
    Slope= channel_height/channel_length;
    b=menu('Please choose formula', 'Chezy Formula', 'Mannings Formula');
    if(b==1)
    velocity= (1/n)*Hydraulic_Radius^(1/6)*sqrt(Hydraulic_Radius*Slope);
    elseif (b==2)
    velocity=(K/n)*(Hydraulic_Radius)^(2/3)*sqrt(Slope);
    endif


  elseif (choice==2)
    prompt= {'pitch,z (meter)',' Channel depth,y(meter)','Channel height,h(meter)','Channel length,L(meter)', 'Mannings coefficient'};
    dlg_title='Please insert channel dimension'
    num_lines=1;
    answer= inputdlg(prompt, dlg_title,num_lines);
     pitch=str2double(answer{1});
    channel_depth= str2double(answer{2});
    channel_height=str2double(answer{3});
    channel_length=str2double(answer{4});
    n=str2double(answer{5});
    Area= pitch*(channel_depth^2);
    Wetted_Perimeter= 2*channel_depth*((1+pitch^2)^(1/2));
    Hydraulic_Radius= Area/Wetted_Perimeter;
    K=1.00;
    Slope= channel_height/channel_length;
    b=menu('Please choose formula', 'Chezy Formula', 'Mannings Formula');
    if(b==1)
    velocity= (1/n)*Hydraulic_Radius^(1/6)*sqrt(Hydraulic_Radius*Slope);
    elseif (b==2)
    velocity=(K/n)*(Hydraulic_Radius)^(2/3)*sqrt(Slope);
  endif
  flow_rate= velocity*Area;

  elseif(choice==3)
  prompt= {'pitch,z (meter)','Bottom width,b(meter)', 'Channel depth,y(meter)','Channel height,h(meter)','Channel length,L(meter)', 'Mannings coefficient'};
    dlg_title='Please insert channel dimension'
    num_lines=1;
    answer= inputdlg(prompt, dlg_title,num_lines);
     pitch=str2double(answer{1});
     bottom_width=str2double(answer{2});
    channel_depth= str2double(answer{3});
    channel_height=str2double(answer{4});
    channel_length=str2double(answer{5});
    n=str2double(answer{6});
    Area= pitch*(channel_depth^2);
    Wetted_Perimeter= 2*channel_depth*((1+pitch^2)^(1/2));
    Hydraulic_Radius= Area/Wetted_Perimeter;
    K=1.00;
    Slope= channel_height/channel_length;
    b=menu('Please choose formula', 'Chezy Formula', 'Mannings Formula');
    if(b==1)
    velocity= (1/n)*sqrt(Hydraulic_Radius*Slope);
    elseif (b==2)
    velocity=(K/n)*(Hydraulic_Radius)^(2/3)*sqrt(Slope);
  endif
  flow_rate= velocity*Area;

  elseif (a==2)
  choice= menu ('Please choose shape of the channel', 'Rectangle', 'Triangle','Trapezoid');
  if (choice==1)
    prompt= {'channel top width,b (ft)',' Channel depth,y(ft)','Channel height,h(ft)','Channel length,L(ft)', 'Mannings coefficient,n'};
    dlg_title='Please insert channel dimension'
    num_lines=1;
    answer= inputdlg(prompt, dlg_title,num_lines);
     top_width=str2double(answer{1});
    channel_depth= str2double(answer{2});
    channel_height=str2double(answer{3});
    channel_length=str2double(answer{4});
    n=str2double(answer{5});
    Area= top_width*channel_depth;
    Wetted_Perimeter= top_width+2*channel_depth;
    Hydraulic_Radius= Area/Wetted_Perimeter;
    K=1.49;
    Slope= channel_height/channel_length;
    b=menu('Please choose formula', 'Chezy Formula', 'Mannings Formula');
    if(b==1)
    velocity= (1/n)*Hydraulic_Radius^(1/6)*sqrt(Hydraulic_Radius*Slope);
    elseif (b==2)
    velocity=(K/n)*(Hydraulic_Radius)^(2/3)*sqrt(Slope);
    endif
    flow_rate= velocity*Area;

  elseif (choice==2)
    prompt= {'pitch,z (ft)',' Channel depth,y(ft)','Channel height,h(ft)','Channel length,L(ft)', 'Mannings coefficient'};
    dlg_title='Please insert channel dimension'
    num_lines=1;
    answer= inputdlg(prompt, dlg_title,num_lines);
     pitch=str2double(answer{1});
    channel_depth= str2double(answer{2});
    channel_height=str2double(answer{3});
    channel_length=str2double(answer{4});
    n=str2double(answer{5});
    Area= pitch*(channel_depth^2);
    Wetted_Perimeter= 2*channel_depth*((1+pitch^2)^(1/2));
    Hydraulic_Radius= Area/Wetted_Perimeter;
    K=1.49;
    Slope= channel_height/channel_length;
    b=menu('Please choose formula', 'Chezy Formula', 'Mannings Formula');
    if(b==1)
    velocity= (1/n)*Hydraulic_Radius^(1/6)*sqrt(Hydraulic_Radius*Slope);
    elseif (b==2)
    velocity=(K/n)*(Hydraulic_Radius)^(2/3)*sqrt(Slope);
  endif
  flow_rate= velocity*Area;

  elseif(choice==3)
  prompt= {'pitch,z (ft)','Bottom width,b(ft)', 'Channel depth,y(ft)','Channel height,h(ft)','Channel length,L(ft)', 'Mannings coefficient'};
    dlg_title='Please insert channel dimension'
    num_lines=1;
    answer= inputdlg(prompt, dlg_title,num_lines);
     pitch=str2double(answer{1});
     bottom_width=str2double(answer{2});
    channel_depth= str2double(answer{3});
    channel_height=str2double(answer{4});
    channel_length=str2double(answer{5});
    n=str2double(answer{6});
    Area= pitch*(channel_depth^2);
    Wetted_Perimeter= 2*channel_depth*((1+pitch^2)^(1/2));
    Hydraulic_Radius= Area/Wetted_Perimeter;
    K=1.49;
    Slope= channel_height/channel_length;
    b=menu('Please choose formula', 'Chezy Formula', 'Mannings Formula');
    if(b==1)
    velocity= (1/n)*sqrt(Hydraulic_Radius*Slope);
    elseif (b==2)
    velocity=(K/n)*(Hydraulic_Radius)^(2/3)*sqrt(Slope);
  endif
  flow_rate= velocity*Area;
endif
end
```

I'm expecting when I'm running the script, the menu function at least work until the " US Customary Units" calculation, but when I run it, the script stop at if a==2( for US Customary unit), is there any way to solve this isuue, I think I misused the if/endif/elseif function or the menu function.

Comment: Please include your code as text in your question, not as links or screen captures.

Comment: I already add the script, thanks for the head ups

Comment: There are only 148 lines in the script that you posted. Where is line 156 that is reporting the error?

Comment: that's also a question i've been pondering, my line actually ends at 148, but the error keep reporting line 156 which is confusing for me to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `endif` right after the line `velocity=(K/n)*(Hydraulic_Radius)^(2/3)*sqrt(Slope);`.

To help locating such errors use the collapsing buttons in the editor, which are on the left of the code. When clicking of the collapsing button corresponding to a `if` all the code, but only the code, of the `if-then-else` block should collapse. If more code, or less code, collapses, then there is a problem inside this block.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and tips, this calculator is for my hydrology student, but I do not have experience in coding, you save my life :)